# Updating Android Studio to 0.3.5 .Project doesnt work ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two projects. DataModel and my application.
My application starts successfully but then fails with classnotfoundexception. Cant find DataModel project.I used to have the same problem before but I could fix it by updating gradle files although randomly android studio would screw them

DataModel build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

MyApplication build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.2.2'
    compile project(':DataModel')
}
```

MyApplication settings.gradle

include ':MyApplication ', ':DataModel'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean the project? Build--> Clean

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a known issue about something like that, maybe it's enough if you update to 0.3.6.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62011